# For a script for creating a calendar event based on form, the Google Apps Script works when run manually but not with the onformsubmit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

The script is for creating a calendar event based on the data that's on the last row in a spreadsheet, which is the last one that was submitted through a Google form. The event is created in my calendar and added to the guest's calendar and it should send an invitation too.

Here's the script:

```
function createEventAndInviteGuests() {
  
      var sheet =     SpreadsheetApp.openById("1MeIEjwaZypPbdTGUQWQAuI_tmPtn9L323KuOJvkVXXX").getSheetByName("FormResponses1");

  FormApp.openById('1eGMgOsb0aSC6dDLHlwJ0jX5_XcWxL3uRPxCYHPmcXXX');

      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var rowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

      var title = rowData[30];
      var startTime = rowData[31];
      var endTime = rowData[32];
      var location = rowData[34];
      var guests = rowData[33];

      var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_classroom1040cXXX@group.calendar.google.com'); 
      event = calendar.createEvent(title, new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime), {location: location, guests: guests, sendInvites: true});

    }
```

I've used the logger.log feature to see what the variables contain, and they are correct.
The trigger execution log says it was completed with no errors.
I've revoked permissions and reestablished them.
I deleted the script and created it again.
I have removed the trigger and added it again.

I'd appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

UPDATE: I did not have any reference to the form in the script, so I added that line. Although it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

I had two functions running at the same time with the same onfromsubmit trigger. Both were working manually, but only one was working correctly with the trigger.

What I did was to join the two functions, so they would share the same trigger. It worked!